# How to enable live reload in BrowserSync

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I never been good at configuring grunt. can anyone explain to me how to enable live reload from the [grunt-browser-sync](https://github.com/shakyShane/grunt-browser-sync) plugin?

here's my browserSync Grunt task:

```
browserSync: {
    dev: {
        bsFiles: {
            src: [
                '{,*/}*.{html,php}',
                '<%= path.template %>/**/*.{html,php}',
                '<%= path.css %>/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= path.js %>/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= path.img %>/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        },
        options: {
            proxy: "localhost/mysite",
            watchTask: true
        }
    }
}
```

The `src` option is taken from my existing LiveReload task. Which i want to replace with BrowserSync.